# I have a Simulink block error

Tags: compiler-errors, simulink

I made a Simulink model that needs to take some values from Arduino board and show them on an oscilloscope. I am stuck with an error on Arduino setup block, it says that can't find it on COM. I tried in every USB port and change the COM number from device manager but without success.Can anyone help me with this?
I will put a screenshot with error
[errors on block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MHWW.png)

Comment: Have you looked in Windows "Device Manager" > Ports (COM & LPT) to see if a serial port actually exists on your PC? Might be that you don't have the driver installer for the USB-Serial port.

Comment: yes, I managed to upload a sketch from Arduino IDE  and run Matlab and Simulink tests (configuration tests)